# xmllint: Why is there no option similar to --valid for XSDs?

Tags: xmllint

People seem to have bumped into "no DTD found" often, see for example
[xmllint validation error "no DTD found" while using XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317381/xmllint-validation-error-no-dtd-found-while-using-xsd)

The answer is simple: `--valid` is only for DTDs. XSDs need to be passed explicitly with `--schema`.

That is clear. My question is, why is it like that? Is it just not implemented, or is there a technical reason for this?

I have not managed to find an answer to this question, but mind you I am very unfamiliar with XML...

Comment: Man page says `--schema Use a W3C XML Schema file named SCHEMA for validation` so both option perform validation. Name might be related to historical reasons.

Comment: The difference is that with `--valid` you do not need to specify a schema: it is read from the XML file itself.